# SOAP API alternative for geo-autocomplete

Tags: sabre

Is there a SOAP API alternative for *geo-autocomplete* that is available in REST API? Is it *EncodeDecodeLLSRQ*? If so, it is always providing the below response when I try with the below provided request. I get the same response for the example provided in doc too.

```
<EncodeDecodeRS Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
     <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
        <stl:Error type="Application" timeStamp="2016-10-26T03:33:02-05:00">
           <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
              <stl:Message>Unexpected request processing error</stl:Message>
              <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.PROVIDER.REQUEST_HANDLER_ERROR</stl:ShortText>
           </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
        </stl:Error>
     </stl:ApplicationResults>
</EncodeDecodeRS>
```

**Request:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:mes="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:ns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
   <soapenv:Header>
       <sec:Security>
         <sec:BinarySecurityToken>--Token--</sec:BinarySecurityToken>
      </sec:Security>
      <mes:MessageHeader>
         <mes:From>
               <mes:PartyId>from</mes:PartyId>
         </mes:From>
          <mes:To>
               <mes:PartyId>ws</mes:PartyId>
           </mes:To>
         <mes:CPAId>--CPAId--</mes:CPAId>
         <mes:ConversationId>eservices@sabre.com</mes:ConversationId>
         <mes:Action>EncodeDecodeLLSRQ</mes:Action>
         <mes:MessageData>
            <mes:MessageId>00000</mes:MessageId>
            <mes:Timestamp>233</mes:Timestamp>
         </mes:MessageData>
      </mes:MessageHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:EncodeDecodeRQ Version="2.0.0">
         <ns:Encode>
            <ns:Address>
                <ns:CityName>Atlanta</ns:CityName>
            </ns:Address>
         </ns:Encode>
      </ns:EncodeDecodeRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think EncodeDecodeLLSRQ was designed to do what you're looking for but it might just work. For example, when entering an incomplete city name, the service will return a list of possible values.

RQ:

```
<CityName>MONTEV</CityName>
```

RS:

```
<Text>MVD   MONTEVIDEO, URUGUAY</Text>
<Text>MVE   MONTEVIDEO     MN, MINNESOTA,USA</Text>
<Text>FMV   MONTEVIDEO FLUVIA, URUGUAY</Text>
<Text>VDT   MONTEVIDEO TC BUS, URUGUAY</Text>
```

Do you have access to SOAP API? If so, could you please share the complete RQ to see if there's something wrong there?

Comment: It would seem as if you're using a v2 *REST* token, instead of a v1 *SOAP* token.
Otherwise, the request is perfect.

Comment: I changed the version to 1.0.0 in xml SOAP API Request, but I get  INVALID_VERSION error. Please mention the complete request and response.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with the EncodeDecodeLLSRQ request, but with the session token. 
You'd need to use a v1 security token.